# Apache is Adding Javascript in HTML File

Tags: apache-http-server, javascript, internet-security

Today I got a strange situation where my Apache Server is adding a bit of Javascript code just before closing  tag. I tried to find out but could not success what is going here on the server. I restarted the server and then it went away, but after sometime I'm facing same issue. I'm sure my server is compromized and someone is doing this act. Kindly help me where to look to check how Apache can add such code on the fly on CentOS 7.

Comment: Certify that the problem is in the server by experimenting that JS code download with many browsers, including downloading the page using wget and curl. What does that server serve? PHP code? Static HTML?

Comment: Yes I tried it using wget and curl, its serving same content which is inserting a link to javascript code.

Comment: Use `grep` to find the code under your published HTML docs in that server (you don't need to start up the HTTP server while you are searching locally).

Comment: E.g. for `<script>var evil_js_code;function do_evil_things(){etc}</script>` you can do `grep -r evil_things /var/www/` (data directory might be something else).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping on this but unfortunately I could not find any such string in any of the files available on the server. I did grep for all the files including binaries.

Comment: You don't want to _grep_ the `evil_things` string literally, but the actual evil things your server is injecting.

Comment: Search in the whole server file system.

Comment: Yes I had done that already but could not find anywhere...